# How do I update version of Fish Terminal? (Ubuntu)

Tags: apt-get, fish

I am currently on `2.1.0` and would like to go to latest (`2.5.0` currently). Is there a command to do this? Or do I need to uninstall the current version and install a new one? Is this done through apt-get?

Could not find this anywhere in documentation or elsewhere on the internet...

I tried downloading the latest .deb file from the fish [download page](https://launchpad.net/~fish-shell/+archive/ubuntu/release-2/+packages), but trying to open this in Ubuntu software centre yields "Breaks existing package 'fish'"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The best way is to use the package archive provided by the fish project to replace the packages that the Ubuntu project ship (which are very old and contain security problems).

The following commands subscribe your system to the Personal Package Archive run by the fish developers, update the package list and finally upgrade or install fish:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fish-shell/release-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fish
```

As an added bonus, running `apt-get upgrade` after these steps will always make sure you have the newest-available version of fish.

Comment: In 2019 FISH 3 is actual `ppa:fish-shell/release-3`

Comment: huh, Interesting. So why isnt this package registry updated with whatever team ubuntu has managing their apt or pip updates?

Answer (score 5):

Add the PPA for release-3, update, and install

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fish-shell/release-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fish
```